# Resgatando dados da request.headers em node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rotas

ola pessoal sou novo aqui, estou tentando resgatar dados de um post em nodejs pelo o request.headers por meio de um middleware que criei, mas a função no arquivo da rota que esta separado do server.js não consegue acessar a request com os dados e  retornam vazios.

```
//estrutura de imports que usei..
const express = require('express');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const routes = express.Router();
const views = __dirname + "/views/source/"
const user = require('./user')
```

```
//middleware criado
routes.use(function data(request, response, next){
const{ nNota } = request.headers
        console.log(request.body)//teste de retorno vazio
request.notas = nNota;
    return next();   
})
```

```
//rota do post
routes.post("/adm/novanota.htm", (request, response) =>  {
    const { nNota, 
        MercadoriaRecebida, 
        conferente, 
        Recebimento, 
        txtnProdutos,
        cod_mill, 
        desc_produto, 
        fornecedor,
        check_new  } = request.body

    const allReadyExistsNF = bdNotas.some((notas) => notas.nNota === nNota)

    if(allReadyExistsNF){
        return response.status(400).json({error:"Nota fiscal já cadastrada!"})
    }

  bdNotas.push({
        id:uuidv4(),
        nNota,
        fornecedor,
        Qtde_prod: txtnProdutos,
        cod_mill,
        desc_produto,
        check_new,
        Recebi_mercad:MercadoriaRecebida,
        conferente,
        date_recebimento: new Date(Recebimento),
        diasCreate:0,
        mov_lotes:[],
      })      
      console.log(request.body)
    return response.status(201).redirect("/adm/resumo.htm")
})
```

```
//retorno do post no console.log(post) 
{
  nNota: 12563,
  fornecedor: 'f',
  Qtde_prod: 1,
  cod_mill: '125636',
  desc_produto: 'desc',
  check_new: '0',
  Recebi_mercad: 'MercadoriaRecebida',
  conferente: 'fff',
  date_recebimento: '01-01-2021',
  diasCreate: 0,
  mov_lotes: ''
}
```

```
//rota aonde eu queria resgatar os dados pelo header
routes.get("/adm/estoque.htm",  (request, response) =>  {
    const { notas } = request;
    console.log(notas)
    response.render(views + "adm/estoque", { user, bdNotas })
})
```

```
//retorno da rota de get
{}
```

Answer (score -3):

Isso está um tanto estranho.

Primeiro que no middleware você está tentando acessar `nNota` no `request`, enquanto na rota você tenta acessar-lo em `request.body`.

Acredito que deveria ser

```
routes.use(function data(request, response, next){
    const { nNota } = request.body;
    request.nota = nNota;
    return next();   
});
```

Agora nessa rota que você está tentando *resgatar* a propriedade `nota`, você está tentando acessar a propriedade `notas` ao invés de `nota`.

Deveria ser

```
routes.get("/adm/estoque.htm",  (request, response) =>  {
    const { nota } = request;
    console.log(nota);
});
```

Isso é o que dá para inferir que está errado de acordo com o que você postou.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo por me avisar, atualizei corretamente os dados acima agora... tinha escrito errado.

Comment: como eu queria resgatar do Headers os valores usando o request.body também retorna vazio...